# How to check if I am displaying categories on a Woocommerce page?

Tags: plugins

I am using the Woocommerce plugin. I am trying to create a different container for when I am displaying multiple products then when I display multiple categories.

So far in my `archive_products` I have a check for `is_shop()` and if it is then it means that I am displaying categories and not products. So I load my category style containers.

The problem is that if the category has sub categories and you click to see those sub categories, you are now failing the `is_shop()` function.

How can I still know if I am up to displaying available products or if I am displaying subcategores?

Answer (score 5):

I think the conditional you're looking for is:

> is_product_category()
>       Returns true when viewing a product category archive.

You can see the docs at [Conditional Tags](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/codex/theming/conditional-tags/)

A bit of Google searching seems to indicate that this isn't always reliable, depending upon your scenario. [See here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-woocommerce-excelling-ecommerce-is_product_category-vs-in_product_category?replies=3) on WordPress codex.

Comment: `is_product_category()` is for displaying products of a particular category. I am looking for displaying more sub-categories.

Comment: A subcategory is still a category, so I would think `is_product_category()` would still apply.

Comment: @helgatheviking but since i dont display products when displaying sub categories I want to know if this a product page.

Comment: @LuckyLuke then the conditional would be is_product(), about five lines down in the documentation link I placed in the answer.

Comment: @Stephen that would only return true when on a single product page, not when displaying multiple products

Comment: I don't know of a Conditional Tag that supports that, you may need to actually insert code within the loop to see if there is a product. Check the post type.